# ¿Cómo hago la consulta SQL para exportar las combinaciones de los productos de Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, sql, prestashop1.7

Necesito urgentemente exportar todas las combinaciones de los productos de mi tienda de Prestashop para pasarlos a la nueva tienda que estoy haciendo, pero no consigo hacer la consulta SQL para que me exporte bien el fichero .csv para poder importarlos en la nueva tienda.

Necesito que la consulta sea como lo hace Prestashop, para que a la hora de importarlo, no me de fallo.

Adjunto foto de como es el fichero que crea Prestashop.

[image: Foto del fichero de importación de combinaciones creado de ejemplo por Prestashop]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: que consulta es la que hace prestashop? que consulta estas tratando de hacer? finalmente cual es el fallo del cual hablas?

Comment: Hola, lo que quiero es una consulta que me exporte todas las combinaciones de los productos que tengo en mi tienda Prestashop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes desarrollado un modulo o un script para ello?

En la documentación oficial de Prestashop explica como hacer query:

[Db class](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/database/db/) y [DBQuery class](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/database/dbquery/)

Te paso un ejemplo de cómo yo hago una consulta sql:

```
public function getBrandsPS()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT pm.id_manufacturer, pm.name
            FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'manufacturer pm 
            WHERE pm.active = 1 
            ORDER BY pm.id_manufacturer ASC';

    $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);

    return $result;
}
```

En tu caso tienes que usar la tabla ps_product, ps_product_attribute entre otra.

Te aconsejo que para hacer la consulta sql, utilizes [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) o Navicat y cuando obtengas lo que quieres con todas las columnas que necesitas, lo usas en Prestashop.

Si tienes parte de la consulta sql ya echa pero te da errores la puedes compartir y asi te ayudamos mejor.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, espero que a alguien le sirva también.

Comment: Gracias a ti @chuches